# Return parent function from child function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I return a parent function from a child function on click? Here's an example code:

```
function returnFunction() {

    var output = false;

    $('a').click(function() {

       output = true;

    });

    return output;    

}

var result = returnFunction();
```

The result will always be false since the click hasn't happened at the time the code is being run. How could I make this work though?

My intention is to call pop-up dialogs, and I'd like to have all the logic inside one function that can easily be loaded - including the click events of a Confirm dialog box.

Elsewhere in scripts I'd be calling it this way for example:

```
// Menu click triggers the dialog
$('a').click(function(e) {
    // The function displays the dialog and returns the click events of the dialog
    var result = returnFunction();
    // If result was false, we'll prevent the menu access, for example
    if (!result) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I'm aware of the jQuery UI dialog plugin. But I'd like to achieve this without it for now.

Thanks.

Comment: *"How could I make this work though"* You can't. How can you get a value that will only be set in the future? I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem description. If you want to have all logic that sets up the dialog, why do you need it to return a value?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to do something different all together just not wording it / think about it / right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Felix. Right, that's what I was afraid. Then again, I'm not too familiar with object oriented js, or module based structures, but could I achieve this by wrapping the function into an object. I understood that objects are simply references to each other and even later events will change the previously declared ones. Am I completely lost with this one?

Comment: Now with your other code: You have to prevent the default action in any case. You cannot delay the execution of the default action until an other user action occurs. The event has to be handled immediately at that moment. So, you have to prevent the default action, open the dialog, evaluate the user's action (normally you do this with callbacks) and then, based on that result, execute the default action (e.g. following a link) "*manually*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An over-simplification of it is:

Everything stops (including scrolling and clicking on hyperlinks) while executing javascript. This means you cannot "pause" the script until someone clicks on a link.

The typical way of solving this is a callback function:

```
function my_callback(some, arguments) {
    // you can do whatever in here: an ajax load, set a global variable, change some of the page, ...
    console.log(some, arguments);
    alert(some + " " + arguments);
}

function returnFunction(callback, param) {
    var output = false;
    $('a').click(function() {
       callback(param, "world");
    });
}

returnFunction(my_callback, "hello");
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/UnBj5/

EDIT:

I did mention global variables because they are an option, but they are typically bad style. Try to use other means if possible.

If you want more help with it, provide more details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I realised I was a bit lost there maybe. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameters instead. Send a parameter to a function that shows your alert boxes, show a different pop-up alert depending on the parameter, what you are trying to do won't work because its basically a chicken-egg problem.